# Java - Как перенести значения от 1 до 8 с массива A в массив С через массив B?

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Как правильно перенести значения от 1 до 8 с массива A в массив С через массив B? Переносить по одному значению так, чтобы минимальное значение было вверху а максимальное внизу.

1//A-> C ;

2//A-> B ;

1//C-> B ;

...

Код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] myArrayA = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int[] myArrayB = new int[8];
    int[] myArrayC = new int[8];

    for(int a = 0; a < myArrayA.length; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b < myArrayB.length; b++){
            for (int c=0; c < myArrayC.length; c++){

                if(myArrayA[a] > myArrayC[c] && myArrayC[c] == 0){
                    myArrayC[c] = myArrayA[a];
                }
                if ( myArrayA[a] > myArrayB[b] && myArrayC[c] > myArrayB[b]){
                    myArrayB[b] = myArrayA[a]+1;
                }
                if(myArrayC[c] < myArrayB[b]){
                    myArrayB[b+1] = myArrayC[c];
                    myArrayC[c] = myArrayA[a+2];

                }
                if(myArrayB[b+1] < myArrayC[c]){
                    myArrayC[c+1] = myArrayB[b+1];

                }

                System.out.println(myArrayA[a]);
                System.out.println(myArrayB[b]);
                System.out.println(myArrayC[c]);

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: так это Ханойские Башни... по ним и искать надо. Ну или задание непонятное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public static void hanoiTower(int n, int src, int dest, int temp){

```
    if(n == 0) return;
    hanoi_Tower(n - 1, src, temp, dest);
    System.out.println("с какой машины плиты = " + src + " -> на какую = " + dest + " вспомогательная машина =" + temp);
    hanoi_Tower(n - 1, temp, dest, src);

}
```